# Error types in gRPC streaming

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a gRPC endpoint that streams queries and results back and forth, and there will frequently be errors on the server side that I want to send back. My current approach to error handling is just including an an error message to the reply.

```
service MyService {
        rpc Query (stream QueryRequest) returns (stream QueryReply) {}
}

message QueryReply {
        string id = 1;
        repeated string kind = 2;
        message DataList {
                repeated string data = 1;
        }
        map<string, DataList> data = 3;
        string error = 4;
}
```

I suspect it would be more efficient to create a separate messages, so that an erroring message doesn't have to contain all that other data. I am hesitant to make and sync multiple messages because I don't want to add too much complexity. What efficiency can be gained from splitting up the message? Is there a canonical way of doing this (in go in particular)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that it isn't really more efficient to split it up as protobuf doesn't send empty (default) fields.

so, in the case where you set error="foo"
basically only foo is sent on the wire.

Comment: Looks like you're right according to this https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#default, thanks!